# Migrate to Gradle, but Gradle information is given in project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I am having trouble with Android Studio. I forked the project here:

https://www.google.com/url?q=https://github.com/ubclaunchpad/Android-Calculator&sa=D&ust=1514703967854000&usg=AFQjCNHLwSAZ_JER6VlZ8LP6AtTzfUVBog

and cloned it in Android Studio, but it keeps telling me that I should Migrate to Gradle. However, if you look at the project files on github, there are a lot of gradle related files, so clearly the project does use gradle. How do I fix this? Is there a simple solution?

Comment: Might be because of the different gradle version. The repository is using gradle 2.1.3 but if your android studio has different version than it will ask you if you want to migrate it to the latest version or not.

Comment: @mark922 how can I check which version android studio is using and how would i update it?

Comment: Go through these links. [Gradle 3.0 Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=49&v=oBsbI8ICYKg) && [Migrate to Gradle 3.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works fine with me ensure that you open Calculator folder as a project, not Android-Calculator-master
check this photo

[open calculator folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spFxY.png)